# Wizard link Target not rendering in front - Fluid/Extbase typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid

http://screencast.com/t/L3Asbi2E - Wizard link Target not rendering in front

Front side code is 
TITLE

But target not rendering

Comment: Can you please add some more info? How you are rendering the link, for example?

Comment: Like this : <f:link.page pageUid="{foo.link}"> Link </f:link.page>

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the `f:link.page` ViewHelper does not interpret typolinks (that is what you have).

You should use a ViewHelper that does, for example the [`v:link.typolink` ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Link/TypolinkViewHelper.html) from the extension `vhs`. You'd use it like this:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: youvariablehere}">Linktext</v:link.typolink>
```